# micro sign character display differently across editors and how to represent safely in web

Tags: javascript, encoding

I see the micro (mu) character is rendered differently in editors, in different context. For example,

below is from github normal view in a browser. [link](https://github.com/lazyeights/usda-nutrient-db/blob/master/data/sr26/datafiles/NUTR_DEF.txt)

[image]

the same in [raw display](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lazyeights/usda-nutrient-db/master/data/sr26/datafiles/NUTR_DEF.txt) shows like
[image]

the same file looks fine in Mac text editor, vim, and in some web pages like the [official source](https://www.ars.usda.gov/SP2UserFiles/Place/80400525/Data/SR27/asc/NUTR_DEF.txt).

But it shows differently in atom, github raw view, ..

what is the reason. How can I ensure that it display correctly in web pages?
I will be using it with javascript/angularjs to display in custom components, if that matters.

Comment: It's all about making sure that your pages are delivered with the correct character set (almost certainly, it should be UTF-8).  Even then, you cannot 100% guarantee that a client browser will be using a character set that has that character available (though it probably will).

Comment: thanks for the hint. What is the safest way to do it, so that I don't make any assumption about the client, but assured that it shows up as mu. I have a locat setup, with header `<meta charset="utf-8">`, but still it shows up as that wired qn mark in diamond sign :-(

Comment: @bsr make sure your text editor is set to utf-8 as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've cloned your repo and it turned out that your file is not utf8 encoded:

```
00000bd0  6f 64 7e 5e 7e 30 7e 5e  7e 37 31 30 30 7e 0d 0a  |od~^~0~^~7100~..|
00000be0  7e 34 33 35 7e 5e 7e b5  67 7e 5e 7e 46 4f 4c 44  |~435~^~.g~^~FOLD|
00000bf0  46 45 7e 5e 7e 46 6f 6c  61 74 65 2c 20 44 46 45  |FE~^~Folate, DFE|
```

note the `b5` byte on the second line. This is Win-1251, not UTF8.

It looks like GitHub forcibly encodes files to utf8 when displaying the rich view, but the raw view displays them as is, but still has the utf8 content-encoding header, hence the question marks (there no such thing as `b5` in utf8). Compare:

https://github.com/gebrkn/bits/blob/master/encoding.txt

and

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gebrkn/bits/master/encoding.txt

Comment: +1 thanks a ton. Please see the description of the file at the official source.  https://www.ars.usda.gov/Services/docs.htm?docid=24912 . `ASCII (6.4Mb) - This file contains the SR27 data in ASCII (ISO/IEC 8859-1), delimited files. These tables are organized in a relational format, and are best used with a relational database management system (RDBMS), which will allow you to form your own queries of the database and generate custom reports.`  I will read more about how to make sure /convert it to utf-8. Any pointers appreciated. thanks again. cheers.

Comment: Yes, that confirms it - ISO 8859-1 aka Latin-1 is a single-byte encoding. It's safer to recode your stuff to UTF8 to use elsewhere - but that will break the GH "rich" view (see examples).